# PHP, ООП: создание объектов на основе конфигурации

Tags: php, ооп

Есть класс с набором свойств, которые представляют собой характеристики создаваемых объектов.

Свойства могут быть:

- обязательными — без предопределённого значения;
- необязательными — с предопределённым значением.

Пример:

```
public $mandatoryProperty;
public $optionalProperty = 'Some value';
```

Стоит задача создавать объекты на основе переданной в конструктор класса конфигурации; то есть при создании экземпляра класса в конструктор будет передаваться конфигурация в виде массива, в котором ключ элемента — это имя свойства класса, а значение элемента — это значение, которое мы хотим назначить этому свойству:

```
new SomeClass($config);
```

**Как правильно назначить соответствующим свойствам класса переданные в конфигурации значения, конечно же при условии, что указанные свойства были определены в полученном массиве?**

На данный момент я сделал так, как показано ниже; однако, думаю, есть более элегантное решение, о котором я не знаю.

```
public function __construct($config = null)
{
    // Если конфигурация не была передана, то просто возвращаем текущий
    // экземпляр класса.
    if ($config === null) {
        return;
    }

    // Получаем свойства класса.
    $this->properties = get_class_vars(self::class);

    // Удаляем из из полученного массива само свойство `properties`; чтобы
    // его случайно не переопределили в процессе загрузки конфигурации.
    unset($this->properties['properties']);

    // Назначаем соответствующие значения соответствующим свойствам класса,
    // если они были определены в переданной конфигурации.
    foreach($this->properties as $property => $value ){
        if (isset($config[$property])) {
            $this->$property = $config[$property];
        }
    }
}
```

---

### Update

В связи с замечаниями дополняю вопрос ...

Как я уже упомянул выше, у каждого создаваемого экземпляра класса свои характеристики (значения свойств), которые устанавливаться извне двумя способами описанными далее ...

#### Первый способ

Мы загружаем массив конфигурации в конструктор класса, а затем используем его методы:

```
$config = [
    'propertyName1' => 'someValue1',
    'propertyName2' => 'someValue2',
];

$someClass = new SomeClass( $config );
$someClass->someMethod();
```

#### Второй способ

Мы создаём экземпляр класса, затем перегружаем нужные нам свойства и только после используем его методы:

```
$someClass = new SomeClass();
$someClass->propertyName1 = 'someValue1';
$someClass->propertyName2 = 'someValue2';
$someClass->someMethod();
```

---

При этом, мы можем комбинировать оба способа как нам угодно; например, часть конфигурации, которая одинакова для всех объектов, мы можем хранить глобально и передавать её в конструктор, а изменяющиеся параметры перегружать после создания объекта.

---

Я пришёл к такому конструктору, когда изучал API Robokassa — чтобы закрепить материал, параллельно с чтением документации писал класс (можно сказать, что это мой первый на что-то пригодный класс, так что опыта у меня мало в этом). Там (в Robokassa) есть, например, логин и пароль — они, естественно, не изменяются в процессе работы, поэтому я их храню глобально, а остальные данные: стоимость заказа и etc.; назначаю перегружая соответствующие свойства после создания объекта на основе глобальной конфигурации. Сам класс можно посмотреть на [GitHub](https://github.com/w3lifer/php/blob/master/Robokassa/Robokassa.php), но, думаю суть ясна.

---

Этот способ создания объектов с разными характеристиками мне приглянулся, поэтому я хочу использовать его в других своих классах для этих же целей. Например, класс поменьше: [DummyImageGenerator](https://github.com/w3lifer/php/tree/master/DummyImageGenerator). Однако возник вопрос в правильном подходе к реализации данной задумки.

Comment: Это сомнительный и не самый очевидный путь, подумайте чтобы его сменить, ибо ошибок можно нахвататься.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В целом, *если* Вам действительно необходим именно такой подход, т.е. конфигурация класса через массив входящих параметров, то общую идею можно оставить; есть вариант, как реализовать аналогичный функционал, но с более явным интерфейсом конструкторов, через механизм отражений и фабрики, но:

а) не факт, что Вам это подойдет;

б) не могу сказать, что это будет намного лучше.

Т.ч. предлагаю оставить Вашу идею, но немного подправить реализацию:

```
public function __construct(array $config = null) {
    if (null !== $config) { // от return в конструкторах лично я не в восторге
        $properties = get_class_vars(static::class); // см. комментарий ниже по тексту ответа
        foreach ( $properties as $property => $value ) {
            if ( isset( $config[ $property ] ) ) {
                $this->$property = $config[ $property ];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

1) Я не совсем понимаю, зачем Вы сохраняете `$properties` в свойстве экземпляра? Я не видел остальной код Ваших классов, может быть Вы где-то полагаетесь еще на это свойство по коду, но я бы советовал от этого уйти.

2) обратите внимание на `static` вместо `self` - если оставить просто `self` можно словить неприятные баги при наследовании, которые будет трудно отловить. Почитайте про *позднее статическое связывание*: http://php.net/manual/ru/language.oop5.late-static-bindings.php

Comment: Спасибо за подправку — она действительно смотрится. Насчёт свойства `$properties` — я его раньше где-то использовал в классе ещё, но сейчас глянул — не нашёл, так что это отголосок старого варианта кода. Дополнил вопрос, кстати.

Answer (score 1):

Было бы лучше, если бы вы описали с какой целью нужен именно такого рода функционал, а то мы здесь своими советами можем только усугубить ситуацию (может мы советуем как улучшить 5-е колесо в автомобиле), вместо того чтобы показать|посоветовать реальный способ решения.

Лично я, для работы такого типа использывал бы [ReflectionClass](http://php.net/manual/en/class.reflectionclass.php) у которго тоже имеется [getProperties](http://php.net/manual/en/reflectionclass.getproperties.php) который так же дает возможность получить свойства, но он еще дает возможность поиграться с областью видимости.

Но как я писал - ето совет в слепую.

---

**Update**

Я попросил уточнить, потому как даного рода конфигурирование мне показалось каким-то пугающим, так как принимаемый массив в качестве конфига нам ни о чём не говорит, потому что это просто массив, и что там внутри не понятно, в связи с тем что PHP слабо типизированный язык, нам ничто не гарантирует что под конкретным ключом массива будут именно те данные которы мы ожидаем и которые можно корректно использовать.

В данном случаи я бы передавал объект в качестве конфигуратора, класс которого имплементирует интерфейс, в таком случаи можно указать в конструкторе что мы ожидаем конкретный обьект который относиться к конкретному интерфейсу, к тому же можно часть функционала отдать данному объекту, та и лишаемся разного рода проверок внутри класса который данный конфиг использует.

Comment: Механизм отражений можно применять для решения подобного рода задач, можно создать с его помощью более умные фабрики объектов, заодно вынося код инициализации и конфигурации объекта в обязанность фабрики, но стоит помнить, что это довольно накладно по производительности, поэтому я бы все таки советовал избегать его применения. К слову, "игра" с областью видимости (тяжелая процедура, к слову) - это хорошо, например, для тестов, но вряд ли хорошо для подобной задачи, а вот исключения, которые бросает `ReflectionAPI` - могут быть полезными.

Comment: Дополнил вопрос — изначально решил не растягивать его, думая что и так будет всё понятно.

Comment: @IgorKarpenko насчет того, что это накладно по производительности я не знал, спасибо, учту.